# Mixing 18awg wire and 16awg wire on a ceiling fan installation

Tags: electrical

I am moving a minkaire ceiling fan from a flat kithen ceiling to a sloped family room ceiling.  The slope of the fm rm ceiling requires that a 1 foot extension be added to the fan to avoid having the blades touch the ceiling.  The fan has a receiving unit on it that receives signals from the wall switch unit, which controls various aspects of the fan and it's lights.  The extension will require me to add extensions to the wires from the ceiling down to the fan unit.  All of the wires on the receiving unit and wall switch are 18 awg stranded wires.  I can not find 18 awg at either HD or Lowes.  The closest they have is 16 awg.  Is it safe to make my 1 foot extensions out of 16 awg wire?

Comment: What *type* of 16AWG wire are we talking about here? AWM? MTW? THHN? TFFN? Primary wire? Something more exotic?!

Comment: Are any of these power cables?

Comment: If these are signal wires (low voltage, say 24V or less) you may want to look at thermostat or plenum cables. These are routinely available with thin stranded wires. But you'll have to be clear this is for low-voltage signalling and not 110V power to the fan or lights. The fan's manufacturer may have an old manual you can download to confirm this.

Comment: Can you post the model of the fan, and do they provide instructions on how to extend the downrod?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the 16-gauge will work just fine.  Make sure your connections are well insulated.  P.

Answer (score 0):

14AWG is the minimum legal size usable for AC power wiring in the US.  That's why you don't find anything smaller.

Smaller wires are legal inside an appliance or as the leads to a lamp.  But if you are extending power, that is part of the power system, not the lamp, and should use the appropriate wire size for your circuit.

Signal wires are a different matter and can be as small as 18AWG.  You are always allowed to use a larger size wire, so no need to go crazy trying to find a particular size.

Comment: I suspect these wires are technically part of the fixture at this point, not part of the mains wiring system...

Comment: Not true for fixtures. Fixtures can use wire as small as 18 awg. If there is not enough room to splice 14 awg, 16 awg wire would work but it cannot be used beyond the box / mount. 402.6 allows 18 minimum size.

Answer (score 0):

You said all of the wires on the receiving unit and wall switch are 18 awg stranded wires. I can not imagine a wall switch wired with 18AWG and carrying anything but low voltage - certainly a code violation in the USA if it is carrying 120V or higher..

The minimum gauge for carrying 120v to a ceiling fan / light is 14awg.

If it is truly a low voltage system (control circuit - like a garage
 door opener wall switch or door bell switch) going up from 18(smaller)
 to 16(thicker wire) should not be an issue.

> If it is not low voltage - you have a bigger problem - the wiring is
>   not in code and is really a fire waiting to happen.

Comment: fixture wire is allowed to be smaller than regular wiring 18 awg is totally legal and safe inside a listed fixture.